# C - Why is my merge function not working?

Tags: c, mergesort

I'm trying to create a merge function for a C program and the compiler has been complaining about two problems that I can't figure out how to fix them.

> **First:** array type 'int *[20]' is not assignable temp = (int *) malloc ( 20 * sizeof(int));
>
> **Second:** incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'int *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
>   a[start+i]=temp[i];

```
void merge(int* a, int begin, int middle, int end)
{

    int* temp[20] = {0};
    temp = (int *) malloc ( 20 * sizeof(int));

    int i = begin;        
    int m = middle + 1;

    int k = 0;

    while(i <= middle && m <= end)
    {
        if(a[i] <= a[m])
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            temp[k++] = a[m++];
    }

    while(i <= middle)
        temp[k++] = a[i++];

    while(m <= end)
        temp[k++] = a[m++];

    for(i = 0; i < k; i++) 
        a[start + i] = temp[i];
    free(temp);
}
```

any help or pointers would be much appreciated :)

Comment: just do `int temp[20] = {0};` you'll create a local/1D array: both problems fixed.

Comment: **Problem 1**: The line `int* temp[20] = {0};` declares an array of 20 `int *` (pointers) initialized to NULL and the line `temp = (int *) malloc ( 20 * sizeof(int));` allocate an array of 20 `int`.

Comment: I changed int* temp[20] = {0}; to int temp[20] = {0};, first problem is still occuring tho..

Answer (score -1):

you can use this:

```
int* temp;
temp=malloca(20*sizeof(int));
```

after this declaration to access elements pointed by temp you can use this: for example we want to access element i

```
int y= (int)(*(temp+i));// the step i equal to size of integer
```

you can refer to this concept and write again your code (at the end an array is memory address that store data so we can use the start address of this array to access its different
 elements)

Comment: Never use unnecesary casts or cast if you don't really understand why you should. And don't use pointer arithmetics in array context. What's wrong with `y = temp[i]`?

Comment: It is the same as the index operator. But it is less readable, which is a major target for modern software development. But it is fine if you want to obfuscate your code as you do with the cast.For that, may I recommend using `void *` throughout the code and cast to the actual types each time? Oh, and you definitvely should avoid identifiers with more than one letter.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your intent correctly you are using pointers wrong.

int* temp[20] is same as int ** temp;

That line it self create an array of 20 int pointers int*.
If you are trying to store just 20 ints you are good with int temp[20];
If you are trying to store 20 int pointers then you are good with int* temp[20];
Once you define the size of your array why would you use malloc again on it?? Use realloc if you have to resize the array. To read about realloc use man malloc it also gives instruction for realloc.

Best of Luck.

Comment: "int* temp[20] is same as int ** temp;" is *completely wrong*.

Comment: The only thing wrong about it is temp has 20 fixed in first expression. In second its not known. If you don't agree how do you explain char * argv[] is same as char ** argv???

Comment: If you're talking about the arguments to `main()`, the reason why `char **argv` is equivalent to `char *argv[]` is specific to function parameters. If you read about it in C11 draft standard n1570, *6.3 Conversions 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators* and *6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)*, you'd understand.

Comment: I have used this expression outside of functions too. I don't know what C11 draft says or anything along those lines but with GCC compiler int **<varialbe_name> is a two dimentional array.

Comment: Haha, no, it *really* isn't. Maybe you *should* spend some time learning C before attempting to answer questions about it. A small teaser: Try `sizeof()` a few arrays and pointers, see if you can spot a difference...

Comment: @learner: You are way wrong! `int **` is not a 2D array, whoever told you should not teach C. A pointer is not an array and `int (*)[]` is something very different than `int **`. The standard is a gfood read and stack overflow povides a lot of answers for that, too.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I got confused between *(*(arrayname + i subscript)+ j subscript) == arrayname[i][j];  is same as any int** can point to a double dimension array.